# How to integrate Wordpress Website into ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, peachpie

I am a .Net Developer. I don't know anything about WordPress.
I got a website project. The some parts of project are created in WordPress.
I have to add some new functionality in existing project.
My question is that can I integrate existing WordPress website into ASP.Net(VS2010)?
I want to run both WordPress website and My Asp.Net Website together.
If it is possible then How can I do this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Add new functionality to the blog itself? Or have a website that works with it?

Answer (score 2):

[Peachpie](https://www.peachpie.io/2017/10/wordpress-plugin-csharp.html) has been recently released. **WordPress** can be compiled to and executed on .NET (asp.net and .net core) with Peachpie. You can also write WordPress plugins in c#, so it can be a good choice for your problem.

Comment: Do you have a demo of how to write a WordPress plugin in C# and deploy it within WordPress using PeachPie?

Comment: Sorry I don't. I just download it and make a few modifications, but I didn't deepen on it.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to go with integrating Wordpress and ASP.NET is by using one of the supported XML-RPC protocols. You can see more about it here: http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support

or

use Orchard http://www.orchardproject.net/ is the must close System to wordpress at ASP.net and it's actually very good one! it's the best open source CMS in ASP.net the architecture of the system is very like wordpress.